# Não Remover Data Frame Específico

Tags: r

Estou trabalhando com diversos `DF` (mais de 30), porém quero excluir todos, exceto um específico. Exemplo dos meus `DF`:

```
DF1

VCBGF2

FGFR3

BBTYI4

QQASX5

RRTPS6

DF7

TTIPMBBT8

DF9

DF10
```

Assim, quero excluir 9 `DF's`, exceto o DF 7. Como faço para manter somente o `DF7`?

Answer (score 5):

A seguinte função não remove objetos de classe `obj.class` que correspondam a `pattern`.

```
keepObject <- function(pattern, obj.class, envir = .GlobalEnv){
  obj <- ls(envir = envir)
  obj <- obj[!grepl(pattern = pattern, obj)]
  i <- unlist(lapply(obj, function(o) inherits(get(o), obj.class)))
  rm(list = obj[i], envir = envir)
}

ls(pattern = "^DF")
# [1] "DF1"  "DF10" "DF2"  "DF3"  "DF4"  "DF5"  "DF6"  "DF7"  "DF8" 
#[10] "DF9"
```

O padrão `"DF7"` corresponde a strings que contenham `"DF7"`. Se quiser pode usar outras expressões regulares, como por exemplo `"^DF7$"`.

```
keepObject("DF7", "data.frame")
ls(pattern = "^DF")
#[1] "DF7"
```

**Dados.**

```
DF1 <- data.frame(a = 1:10)
DF2 <- data.frame(a = 1:10)
DF3 <- data.frame(a = 1:10)
DF4 <- data.frame(a = 1:10)
DF5 <- data.frame(a = 1:10)
DF6 <- data.frame(a = 1:10)
DF7 <- data.frame(a = 1:10)
DF8 <- data.frame(a = 1:10)
DF9 <- data.frame(a = 1:10)
DF10 <- data.frame(a = 1:10)
```

Comment: Obrigado. Vou editar e especificar melhor minha dúvida. Desculpe.